# How to send page item values to another page without appending in url Apex 5.1.3

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to redirect to another page on button click and I am setting an item value of 2nd page with value from  first page. 
[image]

But I can see that it is sent as a query string  **http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=104:3:16676730353670::NO:RP:P3_NEW:hi**

Is there any way I can send this as hidden without appending to query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to *pull* instead of *push*.

Value of P5_FINALTABLE should be in session state (for example, *submit it when Enter pressed*), otherwise it won't work.

Then, set P3_NEW item's "Default value" to "PL/SQL Function body" as

```
return :P5_FINALTABLE;
```

Run Page 5, enter something (for example, 555) into P5_FINALTABLE, press Enter, navigate to Page 3 and - 555 should be visible in P3_NEW item.

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot. After I navigate to the second page, I am not able to see the value immediately. If i refresh 2nd page, then the value appears. That means redirect to the page is happening before the P5_FINALTABLE  value is set to session.  On click of button I have dynamic action which executes pl/sql to set the value to session **begin

APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P5_FINALTABLE', V('P5_FINALTABLE'));
END; **. Then I created a Branches to be called after submit page on click of this button, to redirect to the 2 page. However in the 2nd page after refresh only the value appears

Comment: Did you submit P5 item when Enter is pressed?

Comment: p5 item is hidden. On click of save button I am executing a dynamic action which does 2 things. 1. Executing a js code to set value of this hidden item like $s('P5_FINALTABLE', $('#data_panel').html()); 2. Executing a plsql to set this to session like begin APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P5_FINALTABLE', V('P5_FINALTABLE')); END;

Comment: I think it is the problem with the size of data. For small string im able to see it immediately in next page. Thank you @Littlefoot  for the help

Comment: Aha, I didn't know that P5 item is hidden. OK, I'm glad you made it work!